# How to query a database to return the movies a certain actor has acted in?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The database is as followed:

```
actors(PK(AID), name) 

movies(PK(MID), name) 

actor_role(FK(MID), FK(AID), rolename)
```

and one of the actor names are 'Charlie Chaplin', and i need it to return the movies that he has acted in and i cannot get the query to return that.

The current query i have is

```
select movie.name
from movies, actors
where actors.name = 'Charlie Chaplin'
```

and it just returns all of the movies and not the ones specific to him acting in them.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your query:

```
select M.name
from movies M
  join actor_role AR on AR.MID = M.MID
  join actors A on A.AID = AR.AID
where A.name = 'Charlie Chaplin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner join:

```
SELECT movie.name
FROM movies, actors, actor_role
WHERE actors.name = 'Charlie Chaplin' AND
    movies.MID = actor_role.MID AND
    actors.AID = actor_role.AID
```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax, and your answers would be more likely to be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

actors and movies has no relations you must use actor_role for join actors and movies

```
    SELECT movie.name
    FROM actor_role as ar
         inner join actors as a
         on ar.AID = a.AID
         INNER JOIN movies as m 
         ON ar.MID = 
    WHERE a.name = 'Charlie Chaplin'
```

Comment: THIS WORKED. THANK YOU SO MUCH.